# Unable to Login in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I am new to spring boot, i am trying to login in my application. I am facing some issues.
I am not able to login. It cant authenticate to login with my credential and return with message login invalid.
I want the user to be authenticate  when they try to access client site (eg localhost:8080/). I also want to implement logout when user dont valid on a link file.
Here is my main application

```
    package oidc.controller;

import eu.olympus.client.interfaces.UserClient;
import eu.olympus.model.Attribute;
import eu.olympus.model.AttributeIdentityProof;
import eu.olympus.model.Operation;
import eu.olympus.model.Policy;
import eu.olympus.model.Predicate;
import eu.olympus.model.exceptions.AuthenticationFailedException;
import eu.olympus.model.exceptions.ExistingUserException;
import eu.olympus.model.exceptions.OperationFailedException;
import eu.olympus.model.exceptions.TokenGenerationException;
import eu.olympus.model.exceptions.UserCreationFailedException;
import eu.olympus.model.server.rest.IdentityProof;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.validation.Valid;
import oidc.model.AttributeContainer;
import oidc.model.ChangeAttributesRequest;
import oidc.model.ChangePasswordRequest;
import oidc.model.CreateUserRequest;
import oidc.model.DeleteAccountRequest;
import oidc.model.LoginRequest;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.exception.ExceptionUtils;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.RedirectView;

@Controller
public class OidcController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(OidcController.class);

    @Autowired
    UserClient userClient;

    @Autowired
    Policy policy;

    // Login
    @RequestMapping("/login")
    public String login(Model model, @RequestParam String redirect_uri, @RequestParam String state, @RequestParam String nonce, HttpServletRequest request) {
        request.getSession().setAttribute("redirectUrl", redirect_uri);
        request.getSession().setAttribute("state", state);
        request.getSession().setAttribute("nonce", nonce);
        LoginRequest loginRequest = new LoginRequest();
        model.addAttribute("loginRequest", loginRequest);
        policy.setPolicyId(nonce);
        return "/login";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/loginFailed")
    public String login(Model model) {
        LoginRequest loginRequest = new LoginRequest();
        model.addAttribute("loginRequest", loginRequest);
        model.addAttribute("loginError", true);
        return "/login";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/loginPage")
    public String loginPage(Model model) {
        LoginRequest loginRequest = new LoginRequest();
        model.addAttribute("loginRequest", loginRequest);
        model.addAttribute("hasCreated", false);
        return "/login";
    }

    @PostMapping("/authenticate")
    public RedirectView authenticate(LoginRequest loginRequest, Model model, HttpServletRequest request) throws AuthenticationFailedException, TokenGenerationException {
        try {

            // TODO We need to get the audience somehow?
            policy.getPredicates().add(new Predicate("audience", Operation.REVEAL, new Attribute("olympus-service-provider")));

            
            
            String token = userClient.authenticate(loginRequest.getUsername(), loginRequest.getPassword(), policy, null, "NONE");
            model.addAttribute("username", loginRequest.getUsername());
            model.addAttribute("token", token);
            
            String redirectUrl = (String) request.getSession().getAttribute("redirectUrl");
            String state = (String) request.getSession().getAttribute("state");
            return new RedirectView(redirectUrl + "#state=" + state + "&id_token=" + token + "&token_type=bearer");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            if (ExceptionUtils.indexOfThrowable(e, AuthenticationFailedException.class) != -1) {
                return new RedirectView("/loginFailed", true);
            } else {
                throw e;
            }
        } finally {
            userClient.clearSession();
        }
    }
```

here is login Request

```
package oidc.model;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

/**
 * A container for a login request
 */
@Getter
@Setter
public class LoginRequest {

    private String username;
    private String password;
}
```

Comment: If you are not already using Spring Security, I suggest you consider adding it to your project, since it provides login functionality by default. You can use one of these samples as a [starting point](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-samples/tree/main/servlet/spring-boot/java/hello-security-explicit) and take a look at the reference [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use `Spring Security`. It is a dependency and you can add it via your build tool such as `Maven`, `Gradle` etc. After studying your code what I can see is that you are trying to build security mechanism from scratch.

I wouldn't advice you to do that unless you have a high motivation factor to do so. If you can use `Spring Security`, it is very powerful and equipped with all the features you are looking for. You can easily overcome user authentication, authorization and even it can provide a default login page.

When it comes to authentication, you can have few types of user stores such as in-memory user store, `JDBC` user store, `LDAP` user store or even your own custom user store. Apart from username and password authentication via a `GUI`, you are able to do sys-to-sys authentication. You can easily achieve `JWT` token authentication with few steps just like adding a filter and minor configuration.

It is very difficult to cover and give the whole source code as an answer here but I will provide you a sample code such that you can get a glimpse of it. Please be advice that the below mentioned code is purely for demonstration purpose and can modify it to your standards.

**Spring Security Configuration Class**

```
package com.example.sankalpaspringbootcicd.security;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.NoOpPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;

/**
 * Security configuration class.
 * Created date - 2021/08/02
 */
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    /**
     * Authentication
     * Responsible for configuring user-store.
     * Overridden from WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter level.
     * @param theAuthenticationManager AuthenticationManagerBuilder
     * @throws Exception - Exception
     */
    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder theAuthenticationManager) throws Exception {
        theAuthenticationManager.inMemoryAuthentication()
                //Admin user
                .withUser("admin")
                .password("super")
                .roles("ADMIN")
                .and()
                //Normal user
                .withUser("user")
                .password("password")
                .roles("USER");
    }

    /**
     * Authorization
     * Responsible for security configuration.
     * Overridden from WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter level.
     * @param theHttpSecurity HttpSecurity
     * @throws Exception - Exception
     */
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity theHttpSecurity) throws Exception {
        theHttpSecurity.csrf().disable();
        theHttpSecurity
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/welcome/**").access("permitAll")
                .antMatchers("/user/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated() //All requests should be authenticated
                .and().headers().frameOptions().sameOrigin() //To allow H2-Console
                .and().httpBasic();
    }

    /**
     * Method constructing a password encoder bean.
     * Constructs 'NoOpPasswordEncoder'.
     * @return PasswordEncoder
     */
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder getPasswordEncoder() {
        return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
    }

}
```

This is a very simple example and I will take you through each method. The first method is `configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder theAuthenticationManager)` and what it does is basically creating you a in-memory user store.

The second method is `configure(HttpSecurity theHttpSecurity)` and it does allow you to do customizations to your security behaviour. It does allow some routes for everyone, restrict some routes for only with users with particular roles, allows route for H2 embedded database console, disable `CSRF` (Cross-Site Request Forgery) etc. This will prompt you a default login page as well. You can further add logics related to your login and logout mechanisms here as well.

The third method is `PasswordEncoder getPasswordEncoder()` and it does create a password encoder bean and put it in `Spring Application Context` to be used anytime.